# Synonyms, Product Names, and Shingles

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a product search feature for a mobile app using AWS Elasticsearch Service.  I have run into an issue that I would like to solve by tuning ES rather than pre-processing the query.  Here is an example:

```
Product User Wants: mini farfalle pasta

User's Query: mini bow-tie pasta

What Works: mini AND (bow-tie OR bow tie OR bowtie OR farfalle) AND pasta
```

I have tried building the index using shingles. Doing this places the following in the index:

```
mini, mini farfalle, mini farfalle pasta, farfalle, farfalle pasta, pasta
```

My next thought was to create a synonym graph like this:

```
bow tie, bowtie, farfalle
```

However, when I ran analyze it looked as though ES simply took "bow-tie" and replaced it with "bow-tie bow tie bowtie farfalle" in the user's query, essentially turning the query into:

```
mini bow-tie bow tie bowtie farfalle pasta
```

When I turn the new query into search terms that are built as shingles (to match my index) I get the following:

```
mini, mini bowtie, mini bowtie farfalle, bowtie, bowtie farfalle, bowtie farfalle bow, farfalle, farfalle bow, farfalle bow tie, bow, bow tie, bow tie pasta, tie, tie pasta, pasta
```

None of which will return the product I am searching for.

What I really need ES to do is SUBSTITUTE the synonyms to build singles like:

```
mini, mini bow-tie, mini bow-tie pasta, bow-tie, bow-tie pasta, pasta
mini, mini bow, mini bow tie, bow, bow tie, bow tie pasta, tie, tie pasta, pasta
mini, mini bowtie, mini bowtie pasta, bowtie, bowtie pasta, pasta
mini, mini farfalle, mini farfalle pasta, farfalle, farfalle pasta, pasta
```

Since I am new to ES I suspect I am missing something simple that will fix this.

Comment: Can you merge multiple synonyms to one in user query? Something like this bow-tie, bow tie, bowtie => farfalle. This will make the user query "mini farfalle pasta" which will generate the correct shingles.

Comment: I reality I want it to return results that match any of the synonyms.  That is why I am looking for a way to build the shingles with each synonym distinctly rather than combined.

Answer (score 0):

Shingles and Synonyms together on the same field can cause issues.
For this reason, I have always used them by creating multi-fields within the same field.
One field can have the analyzer with synonym filter and other with the shingle filter.

Read about multi fields here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

In your case too, if you create such multi-fields, you could find documents that contain farfalle even when the user typed bow-tie from the synonyms multi field. This would not match the query on shingles multi field.

But on the bright side, if user's query contains farfalle itself, it would score the documents with farfalle higher than those that contain bow-tie because it would match both queries from synonyms and shingle filters and would add score from both queries.

I would suggest using multi-fields in your case with different analyzers(one containing shingle filter and other synonym filter) and then using multi_match query.